# Can we use core SignalR using websocket without sticky session today?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

Can we use core SignalR using websocket without sticky session today? If not, when can we expect [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR/) to be production ready?
Do we have a simple work around today?

Comment: Your question is not clear at all. Sticky sessions really has nothing to do with SignalR (either the older ASP.NET version or the pre-release Core version) and is only remotely related to websockets, in general. They serve to solve a very specific problem of handling persistent connections behind a load balancer. If you don't want to use sticky sessions, the alternative is to use a backplane. However, nothing has changed in this respect from how you would ever have handled this issue and will never change.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, In the current version (alpha), Sticky Sessions Are now Required in the scaled out producttion environment. But it is now fixed yet to be released.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sticky session requirement for Websockets in SignalR Core is gone in dev builds, as long as you explicitly request WebSockets as the transport type from your client.

You can get the dev builds from this feed https://dotnet.myget.org/gallery/aspnetcore-dev

Comment: Do you have any links to more information or documentation about that?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/scale?view=aspnetcore-3.0#sticky-sessions